# netlogo: how to group properties patches own

Tags: gis, netlogo

I was wondering in what way you can group variables that patches-own to loop over them? I am using NetLogo 5.3.1.

Specifically I am doing this:

```
patches-own[some-variable other-variables]
to setup
    gis:apply-coverage dataset-1 "some-variable" some-variable 
             ;this line above for 1000 other-variables
end
```

and I would like to do it like this:

```
globals [group-variables]
patches-own [some-variable other-variables]
to setup
    set group-variables (list some-variable other-variables)
    foreach group-variables[
        gis:apply-coverage dataset-1 "?" ?
        ]
end
```

But this seems to be impossible: setup is now turtle/patch only. I also got the message that gis:apply-coverage is expecting something, but got anything instead.

What other way can I use to group these variables somehow, without slowing the program down?

I have looked at lists, arrays and tables but the problem is the gis:apply-coverage demands a patch variable. This excludes arrays and tables. Lists would need to be defined in a patch context, but the gis:apply-coverage needs to be called in an observer context. The read-from-string variable does not support reading a variable and making a string of everything and then calling run on it does not improve execution speed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is that you use the ? variable as a string ("?"). This cannot work, because it does not refer to the current foreach loop variable.
Maybe there are better solutions, but I got it to work by using the run primitive, which allows to create a command from a combination of strings and variables.
Here is a short example, using the countries dataset from the GIS code examples:

```
extensions[gis]
globals [group-vars shp]
patches-own [CNTRY_NAME POP_CNTRY]

to load-multiple-vars-from-shp

ca
; Load Data
set shp gis:load-dataset "C:/Program Files/NetLogo 5.3.1/app/models/Code Examples/GIS/data/countries.shp"
; Print properties
print gis:property-names shp
; Select two properties to write to patch-variable
set group-vars (list "CNTRY_NAME" "POP_CNTRY")
; Loop over group-vars
foreach group-vars
[
  ; Apply coverage of current variable
  run (word "gis:apply-coverage shp \"" ? "\"" ?)
]
; Visualize patch variables to check if everything is working
ask patches
[
  set plabel substring (word CNTRY_NAME) 0 1
  set pcolor POP_CNTRY
]

end
```

Comment: This appears to be superslow, are there any faster solutions?